# Why do I get "webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser"?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I'm new to coding in python and I'm wondering if some one can explain why this code works on the second try but not on the first?

I was just trying to open a browser that was not the default one.

first try --> did not work

```
import webbrowser

url='https://www.mozilla.org'
webbrowser.register('firefox', None)
webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
webbrowser.get('firefox').open(url)
```

```
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser

Process finished with exit code 1
```

second try --> works

```
import webbrowser

url='https://www.mozilla.org'
webbrowser.register('firefox', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"))
webbrowser.get('firefox').open(url)
```

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.register), `register` tells Python where the webbrowser with the name "firefox" can be found. You have to pass an instance (`BackgroundBrowser`) or a constructor. In the first code snippet you pass None as the constructor, which is not a valid browser class, it can thus not find/create the browser and cannot register it. In the second snippet you pass your `BackgroundBrowser` instance and thus it can register this valid browser as "firefox" and you can run it later.

The 5th line (`webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser...`) in the first snippet does basically nothing, you are supposed to give that as an argument to `register` like you do in the second snippet.